# Network graph with holoviews and plotly

Tags: plotly, networkx, plotly-dash, holoviews

I want to create a dashboard with a network graph by using `dash` module in python. I prefer `dash` over `bokeh` for its simplicity. I have found that `holoviews` has great functionality for the task, especially drawing networkx graphs directly is just what we need. My plan is to create a `plotly` network graph, and interact with that graph by using `dash` reactions. I have python experience but no experience with dashboard creation with python. I run my codes on Jupyter Lab. Unfortunately, I can't plot the network graph with `plotly` renderer, but I can plot it with `bokeh` renderer.

Both extensions for `plotly` and `bokeh` are installed.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any examples where both `holoviews` and `plotly` (or `dash`) are used together. I also tried reverse-engineering `plotly` code but it didn't help as well.

When I run the following code with `bokeh`: I can get the graph.

```
    hv.extension('bokeh')
    G = nx.karate_club_graph()
    hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, nx.layout.spring_layout).opts(tools=['hover'])
```

However, when I switch my renderer to `plotly`, I get only this output

`: Graph   [start,end]`

The code for this plotly renderer is slightly different to work.

```
    hv.extension('plotly')
    G = nx.karate_club_graph()
    hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, nx.layout.spring_layout)
```

So, I want to learn if it is possible to work with `holoviews` on a `dash` dashboard in the same way as it works with `bokeh`. Or, what is the best way to create a `holoviews` network diagram by using the `plotly` renderer?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, reformulate your question as a single understandable problem with a clear goal.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll do it.

Comment: If simplicity is what you are after, you could consider using panel.pyviz.org instead of either Bokeh or Dash. Panel is a high-level dashboarding toolkit built on Bokeh, supporting HoloViews, Plotly, and NetworkX objects.